# Could not find or load main class message in netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, mainclass

I setup the Netbeanss 7.1.1 and write the simple code below. But when I run the class, it doesnt work correctly and give this message :

**Error: Could not find or load main class paket.sss Java Result: 1**

```
package paket;

public class sss {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("....");
    }
}
```

I searched everywhere but I cant find. What is the solution?

Comment: In what file is that class saved? (ps: do not use HTML tags for code formatting - you only need to indent by 4 spaces to get automatic formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error will occur if the class file does not exist.

I suggest you do a rebuild and make sure this class exists in the target directory.

Comment: how can I find the target directory?

Comment: Its usually called `target` in your project directory.

Comment: I create new package and it worked. likely as you say it didnt work for target directory. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I didn't find any of the answers good, but I had some **čćšž** characters in my directory so I made projects right on `E:\` and it worked just fine.